# Did Martha not notice the Doctor's second heart?

Tags: doctor-who

In the first episode of series three, Smith and Jones, the Doctor admits himself to a hospital (which seems extremely risky already) in order to investigate the rainstorm. We see Martha examining him with a stethoscope, and they exchange a wink.

However, after Martha reunites with the doctor she seems initially to think he's human, and the fact that he has two hearts never even comes up. In this case did Martha actually somehow *miss* the second heart?

Comment: If you think about it, if a medical student were to examine someone in hospital and think that they had heard a second heartbeat, their most likely conclusion would be that they must have been mistaken.  This seems like a very realistic reaction.

Comment: True, but he winked at her the moment she found the other heart. Since he's a complete stranger at the time, it would be quite the coincidence for him to *wink* at her at that exact moment.

Comment: Yes, but from memory that just seemed to add to her confusion.  She could very well have taken that as him flirting.  He had also behaved very oddly earlier in the day when he walked up to her and took his tie off in the street, so she may have been suspicious about his mental health!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [script directions](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Doctor_Who/Doctor_Who_3x01_-_Smith_and_Jones.pdf) make that abundantly clear that she did notice his extra heartbeat but didn't really know what to make of it.

> **MARTHA :** *Sorry, um. Right... Right...*
>
> She puts the stethoscope to left of his chest. Ba-boom-baboom-ba-boom.
>
> But under that, an echo..? She looks up at the Doctor, puzzled. He
>   just gives a big smile.
>
> She moves the stethoscope over, to his right side. A second heartbeat,
>   ba-boom-ba-boom-ba-boom.
>
> Martha looks up, astonished, right into the Doctor's eyes. And he
>   gives her the smallest wink.

Later on when he tells her that he isn't not human, she still doesn't believe it

> He's just rising up, cautiously, stepping out - on Martha,
>   following, a beat behind -
>
> **MARTHA :** *Oh I like that, 'Humans'! **I'm still not convinced you're an alien** -*

until...

> Right in front of THREE JUDOON. The lead Judoon holds up his device,
>   shines a light on the Doctor's forehead.
>
> Wip-wip-wip - but then - wreeeeeeeeeeeeeeee!
>
> **JUDOON :** *Non Human!*
>
> **MARTHA :** ***Oh my God, you really are!***

Comment: so she noticed, but her mind refused to "undertand" what it was going on

Comment: @lesto - Yes. Also, I'm assuming she was unwilling to tell her boss that she was confused, then before she had time to quiz the doctor, a whole bunch of other stuff happened.

Comment: @lesto In a world where we have artificial hearts and pacemakers, there are still plenty of (sort-of) candidate explanations for multiple heartbeats in someone who, aside from multiple heartbeats, appears entirely like a human.  I think that Martha could very well be convinced and understand that there was *something* to produce two heartbeat-like sounds, without "refusing to understand [that the Doctor is non-human]".